# IE6 SELECT HTML tag causes rest of page to vanish

Tags: html, select, compatibility, internet-explorer-6

The following HTML does not work in IE6 for me:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html><body>This text is visible.<textarea>This too.</textarea>
This is not visible.
<select><option value="a">A</option><option value="b">B</option></select>
Neither is this.
<textarea>Nor this.</textarea>
Nor this.
</body></html>
```

In IE6, every time I put a `select` drop-down in the code, everything thereafter dissappears (and some before too, as you can see). All texts are visible in both IE8 and Firefox. Is this a known bug on IE6? Could it have something to do with Windows 7? Or could it be my installation of Internet Explorer Collection 1.6.0.6 that is flawed?

**Edit:** here's a screen:

[alt text http://img63.imageshack.us/img63/7232/ie6selectshot.png](http://img63.imageshack.us/img63/7232/ie6selectshot.png)

Comment: Not reproduceable. There is more at matter. Post a better SSCCE.

Comment: I think you should try it with a proper DOCTYPE tag for HTML page.

Comment: can you provide us with a link and or screenshot?

Comment: @Umar: I don't see how the box model bug could be related to disppearing elements this way. It would have occurred in IE7 as well.

Comment: @Umar: DOCTYPE changes nothing. The above is the smallest reproducable snippet (except the text/whitespace) I managed.

Comment: @BalusC: Every browser have its own way to handle and render the markup, Last month i have very bad experience with IE 6,7,8. Each browser was having different layout. IE 7 and IE 8 was close enough but IE 6 results was sometime horrible. :-(

Comment: You're problem should be the document type that you're using... thus your css...
Post does and better help can be provided!

Comment: @Umar: stick to the question. We're not talking ugly layout here.

Comment: Just copy & pasted your example code and ran it in an IE6 instance from IETester -- and it does not exhibit the problem you describe. Everything is visible.

Comment: @Zuul: how is that relevant? My example is completely without CSS. If it's incomplete in any way, let me know.

Comment: @Erik: thanks a bunch, must be something wrong with my IE Collection 1.6.0.6.

Comment: I just copy past the above code snippet and open the html file in IE 6. It displays what is it suppose to be. Nothing wrong here with the output.

Comment: maybe you can try putting the non visible text in proper markup?(although i doubt it..but its worth a try) put em in p tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> could it be my installation of Internet Explorer Collection 1.6.0.6 that is flawed?

Probably, in as much as all multiple-IE-installer solutions are flawed. They never work exactly the same as the real browser. I can't reproduce this problem in IE6.

If you want to test across IE versions *reliably*, you'll have to use virtual machines each with a different IE installed. eg. using [MS's free but annoyingly timebombed VirtualPC images](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=21EABB90-958F-4B64-B5F1-73D0A413C8EF&displaylang=en).

Answer (score 4):

This problem is not reproduceable with [IETester](http://my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage), [real IE6 on VM](http://www.ultrashock.com/forums/news/free-xp-ie6-virtual-machine-image-85877.html) and also not at [Browsershots.org](http://browsershots.org/http://jsbin.com/itepa3).

Use a better IE6 testing tool :)